# Two gridviews for Android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, gridview

Hi guys im trying to create two gridviews for a row of Json data i am taking in as of a wordsearch game. I need one gridview to be 5x2 which i have working here, but i need another gridview that is 12x12 for my mixed up words that i take in but when i try to emulate what i have below twice i get an error `The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`.

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Puzzleview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

Comment: Your number of column is fixed android:numColumns="5" for this you get that error.

Comment: I think in the second gridview you might have included xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ,if so remove this.and remove android:numColumns="5" if you need 12x12 grid